# Can you force a player to **Bang** themselves when Dorothy Rage is in play?

Tags: bang

When playing with the **Wild West Show** expansion and **Dorothy Rage** is in play, can you force a player to play a **Bang** against themselves (or any other card where the effect can be applied to another player, distance-based or otherwise)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a [post by the designer](http://www.bang.cz/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=488#wrap) of Bang!, Emiliano Sciarra:

> ... you cannot play Bang! on yourself ...

Also, this official ruling from the [FAQ for the Wild West Show expansion](http://www.dvgiochi.net/bang_wild_west_show/bang_wild_west_show_faq_eng.pdf)

> The action you describe must be possible for the player

By combination of these two rulings, Dorothy Rage cannot force a player to play a self-targeting "Bang!".

Comment: To clarify you can only force a player to make a legal play so they can be forced to target themselves with any card that can legal target themselves. And the only card that you can't target yourself with is a bang.